# java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null

Tags: java, android, stripe-payments

I'm trying to integrate Stripe with my Android app (Java). When I try to run the payment sheet, each time the same error repeats and it gives me non-null null error. A week before, it was working completely fine and it occasionally decides to throw me this error. My the code below is pretty much identical to what is provided on the stripe documentation and yet it still produces the error below.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_stripe);

    PaymentConfiguration.init(
            getApplicationContext(),
            STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY
    );

    dollarAmount = findViewById(R.id.dollarAmount);
    buyButton = findViewById(R.id.payButton);

    buyButton.setEnabled(true);

    PaymentConfiguration.init(this, STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY);

    paymentSheet = new PaymentSheet(this, result -> {
        onPaymentSheetResult(result);
    });

    buyButton.setOnClickListener(v -> presentPaymentSheet());

    fetchInitData();

}

private void fetchInitData() {
    // Pass in the value here to send to server to charge the right amount
    final String requestJson = "{}";
    Double price = Double.valueOf(getIntent().getStringExtra("amount"));
    double amount = price;
    Map<String, Object> payMap = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, Object> itemMap = new HashMap<>();
    List<Map<String, Object>> itemList = new ArrayList<>();
    payMap.put("currency", "aud");
    itemMap.put("id", "photo_subscription");
    itemMap.put("amount", amount);
    itemList.add(itemMap);
    payMap.put("items", itemList);
    String json = new Gson().toJson(payMap);
    final RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(
            json,
            MediaType.get("application/json; charset=utf-8")
    );

    final Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(BACKEND_URL + "payment-sheet")
            .post(requestBody)
            .build();

    new OkHttpClient()
            .newCall(request)
            .enqueue(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull IOException e) {
                    // Handle failure
                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(
                        @NotNull Call call,
                        @NotNull Response response
                ) throws IOException {
                    if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Handle failure
                    } else {
                        final JSONObject responseJson = parseResponse(response.body());

                        paymentIntentClientSecret = responseJson.optString("paymentIntent");
                        customerId = responseJson.optString("customer");
                        ephemeralKeySecret = responseJson.optString("ephemeralKey");

                        runOnUiThread(() -> buyButton.setEnabled(true));
                    }
                }
            });
}

private JSONObject parseResponse(ResponseBody responseBody) {
    if (responseBody != null) {
        try {
            return new JSONObject(responseBody.string());
        } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
            Log.e("App", "Error parsing response", e);
        }
    }
    return new JSONObject();
}

private void presentPaymentSheet() {
    paymentSheet.presentWithPaymentIntent(
            paymentIntentClientSecret,
            new PaymentSheet.Configuration(
                    "Scarlett Saturdays",
                    new PaymentSheet.CustomerConfiguration(
                            customerId,
                            ephemeralKeySecret
                    )
            )
    );
}
```

This is the error I get:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.gwagon, PID: 6495
java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter, parameter id
    at com.stripe.android.paymentsheet.PaymentSheet$CustomerConfiguration.<init>(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.example.gwagon.StripePayment.presentPaymentSheet(StripePayment.java:166)
    at com.example.gwagon.StripePayment.lambda$onCreate$1$StripePayment(StripePayment.java:96)
    at com.example.gwagon.-$$Lambda$StripePayment$xmpk3Z54kFvY_T74VYWd7R8Sd2s.onClick(Unknown Source:2)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
    at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
    at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

It was working completely fine one day and all of a sudden it stopped working.

Comment: In `new PaymentSheet.CustomerConfiguration()` - one of the two parameters you provided is null and cannot be.  (Likely the `customerId` parameter).  It is not set until the json returns (which is asynchronous) so you'll need to ensure it is set before calling `presentPaymentSheet`'.

Comment: Where do you define and initialize the `customerId`? Seems it's `null` when you create a `new PaymentSheet.CustomerConfiguration()`

Comment: `Log` out your JSON to see what values you have before passing them on

Comment: I assumed that a customer id is created each when the user uses the app for the first time and if it's an existing user, the app is able to pull that value